# How to sort a dict by a specific location in the list in its value?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d1= {'a':[1, 5], 'b':[2, 23], 'c':[99,12]}
```

Before the dictionary had a list of two values, I could just sort like this:

```
for key in sorted(mydict, key=mydict.get, reverse=True):
    print key.rstrip() + " : " + str(mydict[key])
```

This actually still works for the *first* value in the list, but it doesn't do anything for the second value:

```
c : [99, 12]
b : [2, 23]
a : [1, 5]
```

How can I sort by the second value in the list instead? How can I sort by the second value THEN the first value, or vice versa if I so choose?

Comment: A dictionary has no order: you cannot sort a dictionary. You can only convert it to a list.

Comment: A good guide is [Python: "Sorting HOW TO"](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: You can use an ordered dictionary (from 'collections') to ensure the keys and values are in some sort of order.  Otherwise order is not guaranteed to be preserved.

Comment: Sure, that's fine. In order to sort the dictionary, I actually have to convert it to a list and sort it there. Is that what the code I'm using to sort already does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it does something with the second value: this one is used as a *tie-breaker* in case the first values are equal.

Nevertheless you can simply use a `lambda` expression as `key`:

```
for key in sorted(mydict, key=lambda x: (mydict.get(x)[1],mydict.get(x)[0]), reverse=True):
    print key.rstrip() + " : " + str(mydict[key])
```

What happens here is you take as "key" on how to sort the values, you obtain the value by calling `mydict.get(x)`, now you can construct a new tuple `(mydict.get(x)[1],mydict.get(x)[0])` where the second element is placed first and the first element as the second one.

Since tuples are **sorted in lexicographical order**, it means that Python will first compare on the first element and in case of a tie the second element. Now since we swapped the places, it will thus first compare on the second and then on the first.

You can however, as @Jean-FrançoisFabre says, use `[::-1]` to *reverse* the tuple saving a `.get` operation (and the result looks more elegant) so:

```
for key in sorted(mydict, key=lambda x: mydict.get(x)[::-1], reverse=True):
    print key.rstrip() + " : " + str(mydict[key])
```

Note however that a more elegant way to solve this would be to sort over the key-value tuples immediately:

```
for key,value in sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1][::-1], reverse=True):
    print key.rstrip() + " : " + str(value)
```

Comment: this sorts only according to the second value, first value is not taken into account.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Ah I see, I missed that point. Will update the answer.

Comment: i think `key =lambda x: (x[1][1], x[1][0])` will do it. It's probably worth mentioning that ordered containers compared  lexicographically

Comment: or `get(x)[::-1]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: that is actually a nice hack.

Comment: I made a mistake in asking my question. Not all keys will have a list of 2 values. Some will only have a list of 1 value. When sorting this data, I get results like this: `e : [5]
d : [5]
c : [73532, 4]
a : [65045, 4]
b : [58361, 4]` Is there a way to take this into consideration? `e` and `d` should be last instead of first.

Comment: @Thisisstackoverflow: so you first sort on length so to speak?

Comment: I suppose that's one way to put it. In my head I ultimately I think of it as sorting by mydict[key][1], safely.

Comment: I got here on value burninate (the value tag should be removed). Does python have a sorted dictionary object like .NET does? Plausible htat's what he's looking for.

Comment: @Joshua: personally I have the idea that this is more *ad hoc* sorting (to enumerate). As for a sorted dictionary, the idea is not to sort on the *keys* but on a function of the values)

Answer (score 0):

So this question is old, but this might help somebody. Disclaimer: I don't know python so I'm going to describe this in very broad terms and it might be possible or it might not be. I've done this in C#.

If you need your items sorted once, use Willern's fine answer. If you need them sorted all the time, keep reading.

I found it most expedient to make a new collection object that mashed together a dictionary and a list. The new collection object exported all the methods a list would have, and handled adds, etc. by adding stuff to both collections. The constructor took a lambda for getting the key from a value so that the dictionary could be populated. The collection also exported all the methods a dictionary would have for reading (but not for writing for the obvious reason) so that key lookup was fast. In addition, there was an AddRange method so that inserting would not be O(N^2). AddRange would just append all the items onto the list and call sort.

The extension of how to sort by something should be decently obvious.